# How to return SDL_Renderer datatype

Tags: c++, sdl, return-type, sdl-2

Is this the right way to return an SDL_Renderer datatype?

```
SDL_Renderer * aRenderer;  //Initialize Variable.

SDL_Renderer * getaRenderer() //Function to get aRenderer from other parts of the program.
{
 return aRenderer; 
}
```

Comment: I don't usually use SDL but this looks so wrong.. where do you initialize the renderer?

Comment: A problem could be that you're creating a new instance with `Common * test = new Common();` instead of using the right one

Comment: I don't know this code but there's already an instance of Common, why creating a new one?

Comment: Yes, pass it as an argument for instance

Answer (score -1):

Looks right for me

> class CFramework
>
> {
>
> public:
>
> SDL_Renderer *getRenderer() { return aRenderer; }
>
> private:
>
> SDL_Renderer *aRenderer;
>
> }